# Iterate and Compare through multiple Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to iterate through multiple columns which have the key word: Compliance with a column named `Requirements`. I want to make it very general so I can utilize it with a variation of excel files.

So I scanned through the columns with the word `Compliance`:

Then I want to compare the Column named `Requirement?` With the rest of the columns. If the Column `Requirement == True` and a column with the Regex `Compliance == Empty`, I want to save that column and the requirement column.

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame (df merged)

df6.columns.to_series().str

df6.columns.to_series().str.contains("Compliance")

df6 = df6.loc[:, df6.columns.to_series().str.contains ("Compliance") ]

compstatus = df6.columns[df6.columns.str.contains (r'\bCompliance Status\b ')]

df6.insert(0, 'Requirement?', df merged[ 'Requirement?'])

df6 = df6.replace( ['nan', None],'Empty ")
```

Example:

```
Requirement? A-Compliance Status  B-Compliance Status ..


True          Empty                  Yes
```

I want the Columns:

```
Requirement?          A-Compliance Status 


True                       Empty
```

Comment: Can add a dataframe constructor with sample data?

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
df2 = df6.filter(like='Compliance')

pd.concat([df6['Requirement?'], df2[df2 == 'Empty']], axis=1)
```